# How to connect graphql with angular js using apollo client

Tags: angularjs, graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollostack

I am trying to build a simple blog with graphql and angular js.I'm done with graphql part.Now I'm able to query a database using graphql.Now I want to show the items that I've  queried in a Html page.How can I implement it using angular js and apollo client. I've referred this [example](https://github.com/apollostack/angular1-apollo#install)

As I'm new to apollo and angular,it is still unclear to me.

Comment: The API for Angular1-Apollo is almost identical to the vanilla apollo-client, so I suggest you try reading that documentation first and that might help - http://dev.apollodata.com/core/   then, if you could post an example that doesn't work for you I would be able to give more detalied advice

Comment: ^ Any more details would help in clarifying your problem. If you want to try Angular2 this is a slightly more detailed boilerplate that uses Angular2 & Apollo Client that may be of interest to you. https://github.com/scaphold-io/angular2-apollo-client-webpack-starter